# Write a number inside ayah end arabic unicode symbol

Tags: android, ios, unicode, arabic

I'm working on android application and I'm trying to write arabic number inside arabic end of ayah symbol (۝) into textview.
I've tried to write the end of ayah symbol then the arabic number without any space but it didn't work. I'm using uthmani font.

I want to display it like this picture:

[image]

This is part of the code

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("AR"));
    temp+="  "+"\u06DD"+String.valueOf(nf.format(count))+" ";
```

"\u06DD" is the encoding of (۝) in java.

The result became like this:

[image]

Comment: Salem how about a textView with the symbol of the ayah as the background.

Answer (score 8):

You can use font named **me_quran** with these unicodes **U+FD3E + numbers + U+FD3F**

```
﴿ ORNATE RIGHT PARENTHESIS Unicode: U+FD3F, UTF-8: EF B4 BF

﴾ ORNATE LEFT PARENTHESIS Unicode: U+FD3E, UTF-8: EF B4 BE
```

[You can download the font file from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5sSfXlUp5zbYm93WWZGNVFURkk/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-sun2Tgf2VLcN_SKL_bfgRg)

Example of usage:
[image: Quran Verse end with numbers inside]

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this `&#xFD3E;١٩٦&#xFD3F;` which looks like ﴾١٩٦﴿

Answer (score 4):

I just reversed the format and it worked

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("AR"));
textView.setText(String.valueOf(nf.format(285))+"\u06DD");
```

(font was roboto)

Answer (score 4):

In Flutter, you can use [quran](https://pub.dev/packages/quran) package. `getVerseEndSymbol(int verseNumber)` function will return aya end symbol with the given verse number.

Example:

```
Text(
      quran.getVerse(18, index + 1) + getVerseEndSymbol(index + 1),
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
),
```

This will return the symbol with the given verse number.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using uthmanic font ["KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS Regular"](https://arabicfonts.net/fonts/kfgqpc-uthmanic-script-hafs-regular), you just enter a number in arabic like this "٤٤" and it will be rendered as end verse symbol with the number:
[image: just typed the arabic number]

Answer (score 2):

for swift use this code for quran aya ending code addition:

```
let arabicAyaStyle = "\u{FD3F}" + "\(getArabicDigitFor(value:verseObj.verseId))" + "\u{FD3E}"
```

append arabicAyaStyle to end of any aya text.

```
func getArabicDigitFor(value:Int) -> String
    {
        let numberToConvert = NSNumber(value: value)

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()

        let arLocale = Locale(identifier: "ar")
        formatter.locale = arLocale

        return formatter.string(from: numberToConvert)!

    }
```

Comment: there are optimisation issues in center positioning and corrupting sometimes end of line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ReplacementSpan to alter how the aya number is rendered

for example this is how I did it

```
public class EndOfAyaSpan extends ReplacementSpan
{

    public RoundedBackgroundSpan(Context context)
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint)
    {
        float textSize = paint.getTextSize();
        canvas.drawText("\u06dd ", 0, 1, x - textSize / 5, (float) y, paint);
        paint.setTextSize(textSize - textSize / 3);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y - textSize / 5, paint);
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm)
    {
        return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Uthmani font, such as from [quran.com](https://github.com/quran/quran.com-frontend-next/blob/master/public/fonts/quran/hafs/uthmanic_hafs/UthmanicHafs1Ver18.ttf) or from [here](https://arabicfonts.net/fonts/kfgqpc-uthmanic-script-hafs-regular), you can use the [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)) from `U+0660` to `U+0669` to get a numbered rendered within the symbol. No other font or unicode character range works. For example, if the number is `٢٣` (23), you would create string `"\u0662\u0663"`.

In Flutter you can use the [quran package](https://github.com/aqeelshamz/quran) to get a number inside the symbol, but it only works for the default font provided by Flutter. If you use any other font, including Uthmani, the number will not be rendered in the symbol.

Chand presents a good alternative, but since the number will be rendered within Arabic text, which is right to left, you must flip the parentheses: `"\ufd3f<number in arabic>\ufd3e"`.