# Aya End Of Verse Symbol in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

what I am trying to do is use this symbol with a number in it
like this:

[image: like this]

but when i try to write the unicode symbol sometimes it displays it sometimes it doesn't, and if it does display it i dont know how to write the number inside.

here is a simple piece of code I wrote

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text(String("\u{FC00}"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042907/write-a-number-inside-ayah-end-arabic-unicode-symbol

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine that post is for android not xcode

Comment: look at it again, there is an answer for swift by `Usman Nisar`